# Oracle automatic patch download

Tags: untagged

I need to update/patch the firmware of a lot of Sun/Oracle systems quite frequently. To do that I first need to download the latest firmware snapshot by hand from Oracle's saggy and unsophisticated "My Oracle Support" (list of all firmware snapshots can be found at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html).

Now I wondered whether there is a known way to automate the download of all the latest patches, maybe using a script.

Answer (score 4):

[PCA](http://www.par.univie.ac.at/solaris/pca/) should do exactly what you are describing.

Comment: I'm rather looking for a OS independent script which downloads the firmware packages (all the latest packages listed at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html). As an example, I want to be able to deploy the firmware via the ILOM by using `load -source`.

Comment: Did you look at the [PCA Usage Page](http://www.par.univie.ac.at/solaris/pca/usage.html)? It can download firmware and has a specific command to list firmware: `pca -l unbundled`